# How can I show a list of all pages and their sub pages with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm just wondering if it is possible to show a list of all pages and sub pages with PHP syntax only and without using a plugin!!

All I need is something like this:

About
Company
-- Team
-- Vision
-- Mission
Services
Contact Us

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your template where you want to show your pages list:

```
         <?php 
              $pages = get_pages(); 
              foreach ( $pages as $page )
              {
               echo $page->post_title;
              }
         ?>
```